# Setting up OpenCvSharp with Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c#, .net, windows, opencv, visual-studio-2019

I am trying to set up OpenCvSharp, but thus far I haven't been able to successfuly compile even the basic code examples, despite following the documentation. I followed the instruction from the [OpenCvSharp wiki Windows tutorial](https://github.com/shimat/opencvsharp/wiki/Tutorial-for-Windows) to the tee.

I got the latest OpenCV binaries from SourceForge and added the folder to my environment variables and Path:

[image: OPENCV_DIR environment variable and Path extension]

Next, I downloaded the OpenCvSharp DLL files and added an OpenCvSharp.dll reference to my sample project:

[image: OpenCvSharp.dll in the list of references]

as well as adding OpenCvSharpExtern.dll to the EXE output directory, though that doesn't help because I can't compile the executable in the first place.

I just copied the sample Program.cs code from the wiki,

```cs
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using OpenCvSharp;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    static class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            using (IplImage image = new IplImage(128, 128, BitDepth.U8, 1)) 
            {
                image.Zero();
                for (int x = 0; x < image.Width; x++) 
                {
                    for (int y = 0; y < image.Height; y++) 
                    {
                        int offset = y * image.WidthStep + x;
                        byte value = (byte)(x + y);
                        Marshal.WriteByte(image.ImageData, offset, value);
                    }
                }
                using (CvWindow window = new CvWindow(image))
                {
                    CvWindow.WaitKey();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

but when I try to compile it I get errors for the OpenCvSharp functions and types:

```
  CS0246  The type or namespace "IplImage" was not found
  CS0246  The type or namespace "IplImage" was not found
  CS0103  The name "BitDepth" is not defined in current context
  CS0246  The type or namespace "CvWindow" was not found
  CS0246  The type or namespace "CvWindow" was not found
  CS0103  The name "CvWindow" is not defined in current context
```

[image]

The reference is in place and the package is inluded with `using`, so Why does Visual Studio not recognize the definitions?

Comment: Better to copy&paste the code segment and translate the error messages for i18n.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working thanks to the advice given by Ceopee. Reinstalled and tested a sample C++ project with OpenCV according to [this guide](https://medium.com/@subwaymatch/opencv-410-with-vs-2019-3d0bc0c81d96) to make sure it works, then compiled & launched it with this code:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using OpenCvSharp;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (var image = new Mat(128, 128, MatType.CV_8U, Scalar.All(255)))
            {
                int w = image.Width; int h = image.Height;
                int WidthStep = w / image.Cols;
                for (int x = 0; x < w; x++)
                {
                    for (int y = 0; y < h; y++)
                    {
                        int offset = y * w + x;
                        byte value = (byte)(x + y);
                        Marshal.WriteByte(image.Data, offset, value);
                    }
                }

                using (var window = new Window("window", image: image, flags: WindowMode.AutoSize))
                {
                    Cv2.WaitKey();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Moral of story is to use the correct format (Read the docs!) and make sure to create a new CPU configuration and set the platform to x64 instead of "Any CPU," just like one would with a C++ OpenCV project

[image: Create a x64 configuration]

Otherwise you get a `BadImageFormat` exception. Works like a charm now.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

`IplImage` is the primitive format for storing image data from the old OpenCV1.x interface. `Mat` is the newer format from the OpenCV2.x versions and on. Also, `CvWindow`should be changed to. Since you are working with the latest version, need to update the code or NuGet packages. Updated code is like:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using OpenCvSharp;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (var image  = new Mat(new Size(128, 128), MatType.CV_8U, Scalar.All(255)))
            {
                for (int x = 0; x < image.Width; x++) 
                {
                    for (int y = 0; y < image.Height; y++) 
                    {
                        int offset = y * image.Width + x;
                        byte value = (byte)(x + y);
                        Marshal.WriteByte(image.Data, offset, value);
                    }
                }

                using (var window = new Window("window", image: image, flags: WindowMode.AutoSize))
                {
                    Cv2.WaitKey();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: We're getting somewhere with this code. I've gotten it down to 3 errors, namely that "Mat" has no definition for "Zero", "WidthStep" or "ImageData". Do these have something to do with an improper OpenCV installation? I didn't use NuGet here, just the SourceForge archives for both OpenCV and OpenCvSharp

Comment: Might be. Different versions can cause it. I am not that much familiar to `OpenCV CSharp` wrappers. As I said, there must be something with the function and class names. I have found some [samples](https://github.com/VahidN/OpenCVSharp-Samples) with opencv 3.4.1.

Comment: @AndriiKozytskyi which opencv version are you using? Can you check the examples?